# saving videos with Cloudinary and Parse, from android

Tags: android, file-upload, parse-platform, cloudinary, job-queue

One of Parse’s brutal Achilles heel is the fact that you cannot save videos to the database (their 10MB limit means videos less than 30 seconds long). And so to supplement Parse, I am using the Cloudinary Parse Module. But now I have a problem. Normally, Parse takes care of **eventually** saving data to the cloud, allowing users to upload data even while offline. Is there a way to get Parse and Cloudinary to accomplish this without me myself having to depend a Job Queue such as `compile 'com.path:android-priority-jobqueue:1.1.2'`?